# Access denied error from SES serverless framework

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I’m trying to send an email through calling api from lambda function. Everything works fine locally but after deployment, am getting Access Denied error from SES.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give AWS SES access to your Lambda existing role. Just go to

1. Execution Role
2. Existing Role
3. Click on View the  on IAM console.
4. Attach Policies.
5. Find AWSSESFullAccess role and attach it.